# How to refer to a definition at the end of the page?

Tags: footnotes

I want to write some word in LaTeX and write its definition at the end of the page.

For example:

```
this is an example* in latex doc..



------------------------------------
*example: is ... end of the definition.
```

Any idea on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    this is an example\footnote{example: is a WORKING, compileable Tex Document}
    in latex doc..
\end{document}
```

PS.: There is tex.stackexchange.com for LaTeX specific questions!

Answer (score 4):

What you want to achieve is called footnotes. Have a look at this [documentation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Footnotes_and_Margin_Notes).